# JavaScript: How Do I save the Score and Initials once the page is refreshed and add more score and initials to the existing ones.?

Tags: javascript, dom, local-storage

I am creating a javascript quiz. I am almost complete, but I have no idea how to take the localStorage.getItem and localStorage.setItem for both initials and score and save them to the page I am having them appear on. Once I refresh I don't want them to disappear. I also want to be able to add more scores and initials to the page. enter code hereI am trying to create a View high score list. My teacher tried to explain it multiple times but I didn't understand.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JavaScript Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="layout-container">
        <header>
            <h1>View High Scores</h1>
            <h1 id="countdown"></h1>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div id="startpage" class="startpage">
                <h2>Coding Quiz Challenge</h2>
                <p>Try to answer the following code related questions within within the time limit. <br>
                    Keep in mind that incorrect answers will penalize your score and time by ten seconds!
                </p>
                <button class="btn" id="start" type="submit">Start Quiz</button>
            </div>

            <div id="questionsContainer" class="questionsContainer">
                <div id="question" class="questions"></div>
                <div id="answers" class="asnwers"></div>
                <div id="prompt" class="prompt"></div>
            </div>

            <div id ="score" class="score">
                <div id="scoreArea" class="scoreArea"></div>
                <form id="inName" class="inName"></form>
                <div id="saveButton" class="saveButon"></div>
            </div>
            <div id ="highScores" class="highScores">
                <div id="high-score-title"></div>
            </div>

        </main>
    </div>

    <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>


    
</body>
</html>
```

```js
//DOM elemets 
var startButtonEl = document.querySelector('#start');
var questionEl = document.querySelector('#question');
var answerEl = document.querySelector('#answers');
var startPageEl =  document.querySelector('#startpage');
var scorePageEl = document.querySelector('#score');
var questionConEl = document.querySelector('#questionsContainer');
var correctEl = document.querySelector('#prompt');
var countdownEl = document.querySelector('#countdown');
var scoreAreaEl = document.querySelector('#scoreArea');
var inNameEl = document.querySelector('#inName');
var buttonDivEl = document.querySelector('#saveButton');
var highScoreEl = document.querySelector('#highScores')

//variables 
var timer = 75;
var runningTimer;
var score = 0;
var questionIndex = 0

//questions array
var questions = [
    {question:"String values must be enclosed within _____ when being assigned to variables.",
    answers: [
        {text: "commas", correct:false },
        {text: "culry brackets", correct:false},
        {text: "quotes", correct:false },
        {text: "parenthsis", correct:true }
    ]
    },
    {question:"Array's in JavaScript can be used to store _____.",
    answers: [
        {text: "numbers and strings", correct:false },
        {text: "other array's", correct:false},
        {text: "booleans", correct:false },
        {text: "all of the above", correct:true }
    ]
    },
    {question:"A very useful tool used during development and debugging for printing content to the debugger is:",
    answers: [
        {text: "JavaScript", correct:false },
        {text: "console.log", correct:true},
        {text: "terminal/bash", correct:false },
        {text: "foor loops", correct:false }
    ]
    },
    {question:"Commonly used data types DO not include:",
    answers: [
        {text: "strings", correct:false },
        {text: "booleans", correct:false},
        {text: "alerts", correct:true },
        {text: "numbers", correct:false }
    ]
    },
    {question:"The condition in an if/else statement is enclosed with ____.",
    answers: [
        {text: "paranthesis", correct:true },
        {text: "curly brackets", correct:false},
        {text: "quotes", correct:false },
        {text: "square brackets", correct:false }
    ]
    }
];

// start quiz on click  
function startQuiz() {
    startPageEl.replaceWith(questionConEl)
    startTimer();
    showQAs();
}

//show questions 
function showQAs (){
    questionEl.innerHTML=questions[questionIndex].question
   // loop for answers in questions
    //answerEl.innerHTML = "<ol>";
    
    for (var i = 0; i< questions[questionIndex].answers.length; i++) {
       answerButton(questions[questionIndex].answers[i]); 
    }    

    //answerEl.innerHTML += "</ol>";
}

// make answers into a buton  
function answerButton (answer) {
    var buttonEl = document.createElement('button');
    buttonEl.setAttribute('answer', answer.correct);
    buttonEl.id = answer.text;
    buttonEl.innerText = answer.text;
  
    //eveny listern for going to next question once the answer of a button is clicked
    buttonEl.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);
    
    answerEl.appendChild(buttonEl);
}


//looping through questionIndex
function nextQuestion (event) {
    console.log(nextQuestion);
    var targetEl = event.target;
    
    correctInc(targetEl.getAttribute('answer'));

    deleteButton();
    questionIndex++;
    if (questionIndex < questions.length) {
        showQAs();
    } else {
        gameOver();
    }
}

//deletes the answer buttons so next answers can be displayed
function deleteButton (){
    //loops through the answers array and deletes button
    for (var i = 0; i< questions[questionIndex].answers.length; i++) {
        var buttonId = document.getElementById(questions[questionIndex].answers[i].text);
        buttonId.remove(); 
    }  
    
}

//adjusting time and points based on if answer is correct or wrong 
function correctInc (answer) {
    createText(answer);
    if (answer === "true"){
        score += 5;
    } else {
        timer -= 10;
    }
}

//function for creating a text for correct and wrong answer's
function createText(answer) {
    if (answer === "true") {
        correctEl.innerHTML = "Correct!"
    } else {
        correctEl.innerHTML = "Wrong!"
    }
}

// timer function starts at 75 seconds
function startTimer() {
    countdownEl.innerHTML = "Time:" + timer;
    if (timer <= 0) {
        gameOver();
    } else {
        timer -= 1;
        runningTimer = setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
    }

}
// game over function
function gameOver() {
    clearInterval(runningTimer);
    countdownEl.innerHTML = "Finished";
    displayScore();
    savedScore ();
}

// once all questions have been answered give me a final score 
function displayScore () {
    questionConEl.replaceWith(scorePageEl);
    scoreAreaEl.innerText = "Final Score:" + score;
     // Create an input element for initials 
    initTextEl = document.createElement("input"); 
    initTextEl.setAttribute("id", "initails-input"); 
    initTextEl.setAttribute("type", "text"); 
    initTextEl.setAttribute("name", "iniatials"); 
    initTextEl.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter Initials here"); 
      
    inNameEl.appendChild(initTextEl);


    // create save button elemetn
    saveButtonEl = document.createElement("button");
    saveButtonEl.setAttribute("id" , "save-btn");
    saveButtonEl.setAttribute("class" ,"save-btn");
    saveButtonEl.setAttribute("type" , "submit");
    saveButtonEl.textContent = "Save Score";

    inNameEl.appendChild(saveButtonEl);

    inNameEl.addEventListener("submit", viewHighScores);
}

function viewHighScores (e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
    var name = document.querySelector("#initails-input").value;
    savedInit(name);
    
    scorePageEl.replaceWith(highScoreEl)
    loadSaveScores();
  
}


//function to save task in local storage 
var savedScore = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("score", JSON.stringify(score));
}
var savedInit = function(initails) {
    localStorage.setItem("initails", JSON.stringify(initails));
}

// gets tasks from local storage and load them
function loadSaveScores() {
    // get tasks items from local stroage
    var savedScore = localStorage.getItem("score");
    var savedInit = localStorage.getItem("initails");

    savedScore  = JSON.parse(savedScore);
    savedInit = JSON.parse(savedInit);

    document.getElementById("highScores").innerHTML = savedInit + " - " + savedScore;
   
}   


//event listeners
startButtonEl.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a load event listener to your page?? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event. You can add an event listener and Get data from the localstorage after the content is loaded